# VS Code How to make testing explorer and terminal not open automatically when you run the test?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Every time I run a test, testing explorer opens and a new terminal is created and opened.

[image]

And I can't find the setting whether it is possible to turn off this automatic opening, i.e. I want neither explorer nor the terminal to open automatically.

If this is possible, then I will be glad if you tell me how to do it.